# Confusing export statement in Express module "export = e"

Tags: typescript

the express index.d.ts file contains the following:

```
...
declare function e(): core.Express;

declare namespace e {
...
}

export = e
```

Can someone please decipher this for me? I can't find a reference to a "export" statement that involves an "=" sign with no lvalue; and there appear to be conflicting declarations for the symbol "e". What exactly does this module export, then?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require here you go